# How to read arguments sent to method in another stack frame?

Tags: c++, arguments, stack-frame

I'm trying to read arguments value and type as they were sent to a method prior to me in call stack.

I've read you couldn't do that in `.Net` so I've looked around and found this class which is supposed to provide me the values I need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230165%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Unfourtanly, I can't find a way to compile my C++ project without getting many syntax errors caused by including the `cordebug.h` header.

Does anyone know how to use this class properly or has any other solution?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not always possible.  Can you tell us your higher-level goal here?

Comment: I've managed to compile. Apparently I should have also used "cor.h" in my includes.